# Laravel Eloquent multiple AND/OR statements

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve products from that database that either fall between a specific date range or are `NULL`. In addition, the products must **not** have been previously purchased.

My query:

```
$offerings = Offering::with(['items' => function($query) use ($purchased, $dt) {
            $query->whereNotIn('offering_items.id', $purchased)
                  ->whereDate('offering_items.start_date', '<=', $dt->toDateString())
                  ->whereDate('offering_items.end_date', '>=', $dt->toDateString())
                  ->orWhereNull('offering_items.start_date')
                  ->orWhereNull('offering_items.end_date');
        }])->get();
```

Table Structure:
[image]

Table:
[image]

The result of this query outputs all the records from the database.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share your table details?  and why are you converting dates to string `$dt->toDateString()`

Comment: @Iftikharuddin Added. Hope this helps. I'm converting toDateString() to match the data in the column.

Comment: What is the actual sql query you want to generate?

Comment: @Jerodev Get all products that haven't been purchased, which, either fall between 2 dates (start_date | end_date) or where those 2 columns are null.

Comment: why dont try use `whereBetween` on date range

Comment: next you need apply other `query function` inside to do it `whereNull` and `orWhereNull`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code eventually got the desired results:

```
$offerings = Offering::with(['items' => function($query) use ($purchased, $dt) {
            $query->where(function($query) use ($purchased) {
                $query->whereNotIn('offering_items.id', $purchased);
            })->where(function($query) use ($dt) {
                $query->whereDate('offering_items.start_date', '<=', $dt->toDateString())
                      ->orWhereNull('offering_items.start_date');   
            })->where(function($query) use ($dt) {
                $query->whereDate('offering_items.end_date', '>=', $dt->toDateString())
                ->orWhereNull('offering_items.end_date');
            });
            }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping `wheres` like below:

```
Offering::with(['items' => function($query) use ($purchased, $dt) {
    $query->where(function($query){
    $query->whereNull('start')->orWhereNull('end');
})->orWhere(function($query){
    $query->whereDate('offering_items.start_date', '<=', $dt->toDateString())->whereDate('offering_items.end_date', '>=', $dt->toDateString())
})->whereNotIn('offering_items.id', $purchased)
}])->get();
```